# In this following code why j should be less than i,why j<=n is not working(4th line)?

Tags: javascript, loops

I can not understand the 4th line.Why its not working while i write that j<=n..

```js
let n = 10;

nextPrime:
  for (let i = 2; i <= n; i++) { // for each i...

    for (let j = 2; j < i; j++) { // look for a divisor..
      if (i % j == 0) continue nextPrime; // not a prime, go next i
    }

    alert(i); // a prime
  }
```

Comment: Please try to describe the issue more clearly. I cannot determine what issue you're having. Which line is the 4th line?

Comment: I tried to find a mistake, then ran the code, it gave me all primes lower or equal than 10, which is what it should do, according to the comments.

Comment: @ASDFGerte It seems to be working then. I think the OP is looking for an explanation of some code element. I'm guessing the modulus is confusing. That's why I asked which is the 4th line.

Answer (score 1):

Prime numbers are numbers that are only divisible for one and themselves.

This code works:

```
for (let j = 2; j < i; j++) { // here you have to iterate only t
    if (i % j == 0) continue nextPrime; // not a prime, go next i
}
```

beacuse for every *i* you need to know if there is a lesser number that *i* is divisible for it.

For example:

```
i === 6;
```

To know if it is a prime, you don't have to test 1 and 6, but all the others numbers: 2, 3, 4 and 5. As 6 is divisible for 2 you already know that it is not a prime number and can go to the next number.

That is why you use `j<i` and not `j<=n`.

Answer (score 0):

We are looping through different values of `j` checking if they divide `i`.  If no values of `j` divide `i`, then `i` must be prime.  If you check all `j<=n` then you will at some point have `j=i`, and then `j` divides `i`, so the program will conclude that `i` is not prime.  This is why you must stop before then.  You could in fact stop at `j<=sqrt(i)`, which would be more efficient.